# Unable to Successfully Update Page Content via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a mobile version of a website built in jQuery mobile and living on a dedicated "m.myurl" subdomain. The full desktop version of the site is in Wordpress. My goal is to have updates entered via Wordpress to the desktop site to show up dynamically on the mobile site as well. I am generating the page content from the individual pages of the desktop site via JSON feeds, and have confirmed that the JSON feeds are good (i.e.: if I enter their URL into a browser, I get a good JSON object). However, the AJAX call on the jQuery mobile site refuses to work. I have debugged to the point that I am not receiving any errors in my console, but when I attempt to log the response from the AJAX call to troubleshoot, it consistently shows in the log as undefined, so I am not receiving known good JSON objects.

The functions I'm using to make the AJAX call are as follows:

```
function processResponse(response){
        var update = $(response).find('content');
        $('.content').append($(update).html());
    };//ends processResponse

    function processJSON(url){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: null,
            success: processResponse,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        });//ends ajax
    };//ends processJSON
```

I've set the three JSON URL's equal to variables, but have tried calling the function with the URL passed in instead of the variable, to no effect. The 'processJSON" function is called within the content div of each page section of the jQuery mobile index.html file within a $(document).ready.I'm using 'jsonp' as the dataType, as I assume that calling from a subdomain to a main-level domain would be considered a cross-domain call. That said, I'm trying to get this to work locally, and haven't placed it on a test server yet.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You do of course know that json and jsonp is not the same thing, one performs an ajax call and returns valid json from the server, while the other one inserts a scripts tag with json and a callback function, and isn't really ajax ?

Comment: `find('.content');` forgot the dot?

Comment: fix the type of and it try console out the response

Comment: adeneo, so would it be more appropriate to use $.get with a jsonp dataType?  Musa, no, 'content' is the section of the JSON object that I want to extract, and '.content' is the class of the div where I want to place it.

Comment: When I change the dataType to json, and log 'update' to the console, I receive the following error:  "XMLHttpRequest cannot load (the URL of the JSON feed). Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."